# Sharekit API : Could not post on Facebook wall

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch, sharekit

In my iPad app,

I have configured the Facebook with newest Share Kit SDK code. from GIT Hub

[Git Hub Latest Sharekit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit)

But it has got an error after login.

```
**AN error occurred with App. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 100

API Error Description : Invalid parameter

Error Message : Requires valid redirect URL**
```

I do not know what to do, please help me.

I can login successfully but after that this error occurred any one  has faced this problem.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is  [ShareKit Issue #234](https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/234).

So rather then using third party like sharekit or any other framework, it is better to use original framework provided by `Facebook` which can be found at  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/.

Comment: but it will open fb's views, If I want real native functionality then I need to implement Grph API right >!?

Comment: Link that you have provided in answer, it has one sample project Hackbook. Code is working fine.

Comment: @ArpitParekh : Thats why I have posted link

Answer (score 1):

here you get source code of sharekit

http://hemal.in/post/2012/03/30/IphoneiPad-Sharkit-implementation-works-with-iOS-4-5.aspx

Comment: I am going through this. Thanks.

Comment: Some file is errors are still there if you have idea SFHFKeychainUtils

Comment: i resolved issue and upload new sharekit please download it again. sorry for inconsistency.

Comment: It is ok but still going for native.Thanks. Will try  later.

Comment: Still same problem I have downloaded the ShareKit Library zip at the start of your project.

Comment: i can also download and check its working fine ok no issue i give you code you just replace them.

Comment: I have mention the problem in my question.

Comment: @priyanka : Your code will work fine with old Facebook APP key. It will not work with new keys.

Comment: @Devang can you please give your credential to me so i can recheck.

Comment: @priyanka : hahah... thats funny. Do not you have registered your self as facebook developer to test app.

Comment: @Devang hahaha... but the apps is working with fbfacebooappid so i need your to check. not your facebook credential.

Comment: @priyanka : Are you checking old apps ? Rather you create new facebook app and try it.

Answer (score 0):

HERE is source code of sharekit demo and it work properly

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/sharekit/