# share text on facebook from iOS application using sharekit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sharekit

I want to share some text on facebook using sharekit. I found many solutions but no1 worked for me.
I have imported sharekit and frameworks in my project. Now I want to share text: @"Hello everyone" directly (I mean not to choose from options: mail, twitter, facebook. When I press button share it should share text on facebook, of couse ask log in if it's necessary).
And also I will be glad if you tell me which fields are necessary to fill in the SHKConfig.h file for facebook.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860652/how-to-share-or-post-by-mail-from-current-app/10862865#10862865
See this link for facebook sharing

Comment: thanks for your post but i need to do this by the sharekit way.

Comment: Why you are using sharekit just for facebook sharing when the easy way is here ....well No Problem ... Gud Luck :)

Comment: see this also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009721/sharekit-api-could-not-post-on-facebook-wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `DefaultSHKConfigurator.m` replace the `defaultFavoriteTextSharers` method with the below Code

```
- (NSArray*)defaultFavoriteTextSharers {
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SHKFacebook", nil];
}
```

Comment: what this method does?
also there is no class DefaultSHKConfigurator.m :(

Comment: This method sets out what all stuffs that you need from the sharekit as sharekit offers lot more other than just FB and twitter like Email, hyves,foursquare,linkedin etc.. Can you look for the method in you application. I am not sure which sharekit version are you using :O

Answer (score 0):

Sharing Text

```
+ (SHKItem *)text:(NSString *)text;
//text - The text you want to share
NSString *someText = @"This is a blurb of text I highlighted from a document.";
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:someText];
```

You can download the ShareKit source files and just watch the ShareKit official project overview video [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/sharekit/)

You can read the ShareKit documentation [here](http://www.getsharekit.com/docs/#text)